# Instant crash when trying to convert readline before any input has been made

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm making a simple method where I'm going to use console input to pick a students number from a list, now for some reason the program crashes before I've pressed enter while reading the line and the VS tells me Input string was not in the correct format.

```
 var whoisthestudent = Console.ReadLine();
 int who = Convert.ToInt32(whoisthestudent);
```

So here's the part of the program that crashes, these are the first two lines of the method and when it crashes it gives me the format exception. I just can't figure out why it starts converting the readline before I've written anything or pressed enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `int.TryParse` to be on the safer side

```
Int studentId;
var whoisthestudent = Console.ReadLine();
 If(int.TryParse(whoisthestudent, out studentId)
{
        Console.WriteLine(studentId);
} else
{
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to convert" );
}
```

Comment: Wasn't the exact solution, but helped me figure out what I was doing wrong. Problem was between keyboard and chair (pressing enter after readkey on previous menu)